# Google Apps Script - Lag in onFormSubmit() Trigger and Automation involved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

BACKGROUND:

I have a google apps script running on google form responses. 
On every new form response, the automation does the following: 
a doc template is filled with values, converted to pdf, stored in a google drive folder.

PROBLEM:

The problem is I am currently at 1110+ responses. And the automation process is at around 1100+ something.

Every new response causes the automation process to fire up for 3 to 4 responses.
For example, the 1111th response has fired up the process for 1101 and 1102 response.

Basically, there is a lag in `onFormSubmit()` function and resulting files generations.

WHAT I CAN THINK OF IS:
- I should have used something like `flush()` somewhere in my script.

OR should I let the things run on their own and the automation will hopefully catch up to form submission.

Any help would be highly appreciated since the form is live and the responses keep coming.

EDIT 1:

```
var docTemplate = "SOME VALUE"; // DOC TEMPLATE FILE
var docName = "SOME VALUE";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // Get information from form and set as variables
  var timestamp=e.values[0];
  var emailAddr=e.values[1];
  var firstName=e.values[2];
  Logger.log(e);
  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
  var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName).getId();
  // Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  // Get the document’s body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  // Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
  copyBody.replaceText('keyFirstName',firstName);

  // Save and close the temporary document
  copyDoc.saveAndClose();

  // Convert temporary document to PDF
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs('application/pdf');
  pdf.setName(copyDoc.getName() + ".pdf");
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);
  var fileId = file.getId();
  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("SOME VALUE");  //PDF FOLDER
  pdfFolder.addFile(file);
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getParents().next().removeFile(file);

  // Move temp file
  var docFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("SOME VALUE"); //DOC FOLDER
  var srcFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("SOME VALUE"); //PROJECT FOLDER
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);
  docFolder.addFile(docFile);
  srcFolder.removeFile(docFile);
}
```

Comment: You must not be using the event object available to triggered functions - that would guarantee you only operate on a single response in your automation function, rather than reading from the sheet.

Comment: @tehhowch... yes I am using event object.

Comment: You might benefit from separating your task. When your form is submitted, generate the doc file. Then, say every hour, convert doc files in a given folder to PDFs and move them.

Comment: the 1111th response has fired up the process for 1101 and 1102 response. - Does the script skip 1101 and 1102 generate 1103 etc fine and then later it will generate 1101 and 1102?

Comment: No no. The 1111th response should generate the pdf for that response. But for some reason, the pdf generation process is behind in its work. So every time a new response is submitted, the pdf generated are lagging behind. They are in complete order. 1101,1102,1103 and so on. Just lagging.

Comment: @tehhowch... I wish I had planned this in the beginning. Right now the form is live and the responses keep coming. What is the best way with minimum loss/damage.

Comment: @urwaCFC "we are experiencing technical difficulties", sort your processing out, and then reopen the form. As a part of stress testing before public launch, this situation should have come up...

Comment: Is it delayed or is response[x+y] triggering the action for response[x]? How much time is passing between response[x+y] and response[x]?

Comment: How fast are the submissions coming in? I suspect the script above probably takes between 15 - 20 seconds to execute. It could just be a caching issue if you're not writing anything to the sheet, where are you seeing the delay?

Comment: Okay so on close inspection, I realized the lag I was assuming was no lag at all. Rather new responses were being added not at the end of the sheet but rather 10 entries above. Basically, the script is running just fine. The 10 entries at the bottom are old responses. 
Screenshot to help understand: https://imgur.com/C6g7Cxt

Comment: I apologize for wasting a lot of your precious time. I am really sorry!

Comment: Now why are new responses not being added at the end of the last row remains questionable.

Comment: This usually happens when rows were cleared of data but not deleted. If you were testing the form and wanted to deleted the test submissions you should do so by deleting the row and not just clearing the data.